# Como funciona o evento 'shown.bs.modal'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-3

A dúvida é simples :

> Como funciona¹ o evento `shown.bs.modal` no Boostrap CSS?
>
> Como eu poderia criar algo parecido com este evento ?

¹ - Não como funciona para usar esse evento, mas sim como o plugin possui um evento expecifico para identificar que a modal foi completamente carregada, e que recursos do javascript são usados pra isso.

Comment: Ele utiliza ferramentas que o jQuery disponibiliza através do `on` e `trigger`. Isso já responderia a pergunta ou seria incluído do escopo como o jQuery define eventos personalizados também?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu queria saber como criar um desse, ja sei usar o on e o trigger mas não to conseguindo aplicar pra esse conceito de identificar uma ação com um evento ficticio como esse:  'onRequireByAjax', que identificaria que um requisição ajax foi feita, tipo fazer que o 'on' identifique meu evento personalizado

Comment: Os próprios métodos criam esse evento: você pode fazer `element.on("qualquerCoisa", ...)` para monitorar o evento e dispará-lo quando desejar com `element.trigger("qualquerCoisa")`. No caso, acredito que quando você fizer a requisição AJAX, você dispararia o evento.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss mas eu tenho sempre que puxar o evento quando fizer a requisição ajax? O evento vai ser o mesmo sempre, é uma validação de segurança unica pra tudo, não existe como fazer algo pra identificar todas as requisições em um unico evento mestre ? Digo isso pois tenho um evento disparado em 'shown.bs.modal' que dispara uma verificação para todas as modais em uma unica chamada sem precisar indicar em todos os lugares que chamam modais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O evento `shown.bs.modal` é um evento customizado do Bootstrap relacionado aos modais. Internamente, o Bootstrap utiliza funções que o jQuery implementa para trabalhar com tais eventos: as funções são [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). Para disparar um evento, independente de qual for, utiliza-se a função `trigger`:

```
element.trigger("meuEventoCustomizado");
```

E para monitorar a ocorrência do evento, utiliza-se a função `on`:

```
element.on("meuEventoCustomizado", event => alert("Meu Evento Customizado"));
```

Neste caso, internamente o Bootstrap dispara o evento `shown.bs.modal` com a função `trigger`. Pela documentação, esse evento é disparado sempre que um modal termina de ser renderizado e olhando o código fonte desta biblioteca, podemos ver:

```
const transitionComplete = () => {
  if (this._config.focus) {
    this._element.focus()
  }
  this._isTransitioning = false
  $(this._element).trigger(shownEvent)
}
```

<sup>Trecho de código retirado no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js), linhas 263-269.</sup>

Perceba que há a chamada de `$(this._element).trigger(shownEvent)`, onde `shownEvent` é definido como:

```
const shownEvent = $.Event(Event.SHOWN, {
  relatedTarget
})
```

<sup>Trecho de código retirado no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js), linhas 259-261.</sup>

Onde `Event` é definido por:

```
const Event = {
  HIDE              : `hide${EVENT_KEY}`,
  HIDDEN            : `hidden${EVENT_KEY}`,
  SHOW              : `show${EVENT_KEY}`,
  SHOWN             : `shown${EVENT_KEY}`,
  FOCUSIN           : `focusin${EVENT_KEY}`,
  RESIZE            : `resize${EVENT_KEY}`,
  CLICK_DISMISS     : `click.dismiss${EVENT_KEY}`,
  KEYDOWN_DISMISS   : `keydown.dismiss${EVENT_KEY}`,
  MOUSEUP_DISMISS   : `mouseup.dismiss${EVENT_KEY}`,
  MOUSEDOWN_DISMISS : `mousedown.dismiss${EVENT_KEY}`,
  CLICK_DATA_API    : `click${EVENT_KEY}${DATA_API_KEY}`
}
```

<sup>Trecho de código retirado no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js), linhas 45-57.</sup>

Por fim, `EVENT_KEY` é definido por:

```
const DATA_KEY = 'bs.modal'
const EVENT_KEY = `.${DATA_KEY}`
```

<sup>Trecho de código retirado no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/modal.js), linhas 23-24.</sup>

Se analisar todos os valores, verá que a chamada será, de fato:

```
$(this._element).trigger("shown.bs.modal")
```

O fato de o evento ser disparado sempre para qualquer modal se dá pelo motivo que a chamada de `trigger` é feita dentro do método que é invocado para todos os modais da página. Se for do seu interesse criar um evento que seja disparado para todas as requisições AJAX, você precisará chamar a função `trigger` dentro de algum método que efetue a chamada AJAX. Se estiver utilizando a própria função `$.ajax` do jQuery para efetuar as chamadas, você pode criar uma espécie de *função proxy*:

```
function meuAJAX(url, settings) {
    // Dispara o seu evento:
    $(document).trigger("onRequireByAjax");
    // Efetua a chamada AJAX:
    $.ajax(url, settings);
}
```

E assim, sempre que precisar fazer uma chamada AJAX:

```
meuAJAX({
  url: "localhost",
  method: "get",
  ...
});
```

E para monitorar o evento:

```
$(document).on("onRequireByAjax", event => alert("AJAX feito"));
```